# How create new server connection in pgAdmin 4 by pasting PostgreSQL connection string (URI)

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20722229/470749

It's very common for server connections to be specified in just one URI, which is more convenient than needing to type out a bunch of values into separate form fields like this:

[image: server connection form]

1. How can I create a new server connection in pgAdmin 4 by pasting a PostgreSQL connection string (URI)?

E.g. `postgres://public_readonly:nearprotocol@testnet.db.explorer.indexer.near.dev/testnet_explorer` from https://github.com/near/near-indexer-for-explorer

2. If I've already defined a server connection in pgAdmin 4, how can I export (copy to clipboard) its connection string (URI)?